How can I fix app after having to pkill it and nowt crashes when starting
Falkon is my preferred browser running xubuntu. But it crapped the bed seizing up enough memory to bring the desktop to a near halt, so I had to pkill -f falkon to get my desktop back again. But afterward, falkon fails to start now with the follow output at the cli:
$ falkon
WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
Falkon: 2 extensions loaded
Fatal: Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 
Aborted (core dumped)

I then ran apt-get --purge remove falkon to re-install it, and also ran
sudo apt --reinstall libqt5webengine-data libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 qml-module-qtwebengine

to reinstall QtWebEngine. Unfortunately neither command changed anything. Falkon still crashes with the same output above when trying to start up.
Any suggestions how I might be able to fix this issue? Thks.

Have you tried to reboot your system?

@Ramhound yes, I rebooted after pkill'ing falkon and it started crashing, and rebooted again after running both reinstall commands.

If it's you preferred browser, and you use it regularly, then at what point did the issue occur? After an update, app or OS? Not only uninstall the app, but remove your profile (purge might have not removed it). Then reinstall, updating to the latest version. Or try the Windows version, running in wine.

@DrMoishePippik like I detailed in the OP, falkon locked up the syste, bringing everything to a near grinding halt, which led me to have to pkill -f falkon to free up resources. Trying to relaunch falkon after that is when the problem was first experienced.

It complains about OpenGL. It might be caused by video drivers.
Do other OpenGL apps work (for example, another browser)? If not, then most likely you have a problem with video drivers. Although unlikely, it can be a hardware problem.
Did you update video driver recently? If yes, you can try to reinstall or roll back to previous version. You can try to run without OpenGL, but I'm not sure how to do this. From searching I got QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext falkon or QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1 falkon
